# Разбор по составу слова СПЕЦИФИКА

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

В словаре Тихонова А.Н. предлагается следующее членение слова *специфика* на морфемы:

> спец/и́фик/а

Помогите определить, где здесь корень/суффикс/приставка?

Answer (score 1):

СПЕЦИФИКА, -и; ж. [от лат. specificus - видообразующий], только ед. Совокупность отличительных особенностей чего-л.

СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЙ,  [от лат. specialis] 1. только полн. Предназначенный исключительно для чего-л.; имеющий особое назначение.

Оба слова указаны в словаре Тихонова **как непроизводные**, образующие два семейства родственных слов. Поэтому нет там русского суффикса ИФИК, в системе русских словообразовательных единиц такой суффикс отсутствует.

В крайнем случае, ИФИК - это усеченный суффиксоид от ИФИКАЦИ.

Comment: Вера, в словаре Тихонова онлайн пометы непр. нет. И чем же тогда является элемент ифик в слове ***идент/ифик/аци/о́нн/ый***,класс/ифик/ация. Есть у нас элемент -ифик-аци-(я). Здесь представлен этот же элемент(который называют суффиксоидом) у усеченной форме.

Comment: У меня есть такой древний, правильный Тихонов, со словообразовательными гнездами, а сейчас из латинских корней стали суффиксы делать. Вот, к примеру, СПЕЦИФИКАЦИЯ,. [от лат. species - тип, разновидность и facio - делаю]. В любом случае этот суффиксоид начинается с буквы Ф, а И относится к основе. И зачем И+ФИКАЦИ делить пополам? Называйте ИФИК усеченным суффиксоидом, но только не русским суффиксом.

Comment: Вера, в моем ответе ничего не говорится про происхождение суффикса. Кстати, поните, подобный вопрос уже был на нашем форуме. Тогда тоже возник спор. В том вопросе сегодня я дал Вам ссылку на статью про суффиксоид этот. Там называют и суффиксом и суффиксоидом.

Comment: Ссылка у меня не открывается.

Comment: Исправил ссылку.

Comment: @Серж Можете здесь также опубликовать ссылку, хочу посмотреть.

Comment: [. Лингвистические детективы: Электрификация и янтарь](http://www.e-reading.by/chapter.php/1006422/35/Shanskiy_-_Lingvisticheskie_detektivy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Корень слова в этом слове "спец", суффикс "ифик". Приставки в этом слове нет.